# Call Flutter Function from Android Part of the App

Tags: android, flutter

I have an Android app that uses Flutter/Dart as a library.

When the app is closed it continues to run in the background as a service.
In the Android code (in Java), I need to call a method that is written in the Flutter part of the app.

How can I do that? 
I found some posts mentioning the MethodChannel but I only found examples where the Flutter part calls a method from the native (Android) part. I want to do the opposite.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

in Flutter, after creating MethodChannel instance, attach a MethodCallHandler like this:

```
_channel.setMethodCallHandler((call){
      print(call.method);
    });
```

And from your Android code do this:

```
channel.invokeMethod("hello","any argument");
```

However, it will not work when the app has been terminated even if a service is still alive. I have tested it.

Comment: Is there any work around to call flutter function when app is not open. I want to sync data with server when internet connected. I have made service on internet connectivity change at android side but all sync methods are at present at Flutter.

Comment: Where does `channel` come from on the Android side?

Comment: check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya too late but check [this](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

Comment: Sorry but this code can work only when the Flutter side is 'awake' as the channel can be initiated only when app is in foreground. As you said.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to approach this is to use the native database on the platform to store the data then when the application loads the flutter code can call into the native host platform to get the data.

On android it would using WorkManager to schedule fetching of data and storing it in ROOM or Realm, etc.

On iOS it would be using Background App Refresh to schedule fetching of data and storing in Core Data or Realm.

I think large files should be kept in a shared folder that both the native code and flutter code can access due to the cost of copying the data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, you can't use a MethodChannel directly from a background worker/service. If you want to invoke a dart method from your Android background worker/service, you have to initialize the dart engine first.

First, go to your Android code where you create your worker. Its doWork() method should look like this:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    // Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val myRunnable = Runnable() {
        run() {
            val engine = FlutterEngine(this.applicationContext)
            val flutterLoader: FlutterLoader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
            if (!flutterLoader.initialized()) {
                flutterLoader.startInitialization(applicationContext)
            }
            flutterLoader.ensureInitializationCompleteAsync(applicationContext,null,Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
                val entryPoint = DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(flutterLoader.findAppBundlePath(), "backgroundServiceCallback")
                engine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(entryPoint)
                // You can call the method channel here if you need to
                //val localMethodChannel = MethodChannel(engine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "yourChannelName")
                //localMethodChannel.invokeMethod("yourMethodNameHere", null)
            }
        }
    }
    mainHandler.post(myRunnable)
    return Result.success()
}
```

This code will call a function named `backgroundServiceCallback()` from your main.dart. Now we have to create that function. Open your lib/main.dart file and create a new function right below `main()`:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void backgroundServiceCallback() async {
  // The line is needed, so we can use the flutter engine
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // @TODO Add your code here, e.g. show a notification
  // Also setup your MethodChannel callbacks here, if you need them
}
```

Here you can add your actual dart code, that the Android worker should execute. Note, that you have to do any initialization here again, since `main()` is not called. The @pragma annotation is recommended to prevent that the function is stripped from the compiled app.

If you need to use a MethodChannel to pass any data, you can still do so. Uncomment the two lines in the Android code to invoke a call with a MethodChannel. Remember, you have to register that method channel in the dart code (if you register it in your `main()` function, just copy that code to the `backgroundServiceCallback()` function).

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there's a cleaner solution. You can use [pigeon package](https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon) - it is an improvement over method channels proposed by @Ryosuke. But under the hood it's still method channels, so it has the same constraints mentioned in the aforementioned answer.

There are not many valid tutorials, [this one](https://infinum.com/handbook/flutter/basics/platform-specific-code) looks decent though.

Long story short, if you are a bit familiar with Pigeon (if you've set up typical Flutter -> Native communication it's more than enough), this is what you have to do:

1. in Dart (a file used to generate Pigeon interfaces)

```
import 'package:pigeon/pigeon.dart';

@FlutterApi()
abstract class NativeMessageToFlutter {
  void updateUI(String message);
}
```

2. then generate Pigeon interfaces
3. in Dart (for instance a part of main.dart and `_MyHomePageState`)

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin();
  }
```

4. in Dart (separate class)

```
class NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin extends NativeMessageToFlutter {
  NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin._internal();

  static final NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin _instance =
      NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin._internal();

  factory NativeMessageToFlutterPlugin() {
    NativeMessageToFlutter.setup(_instance);
    return _instance;
  }

  @override
  void callFromNative(String message) {
    print(message);
  }
}
```

5. Android

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    var bridge: NativeMessageToFlutter? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        bridge = NativeMessageToFlutter(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("NativeMessageToFlutter", "updateUI Flutter call from Android in onStart")
        bridge?.callFromNative(
            "Flutter call from Android",
            {},// TODO check this callback
        )
    }
```

6. If you compile the project, you can observe the result in both Android logcat and Flutter console :-)