# ReactNative HeadlessJS equivalent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-background

I am looking for [ReactNative HeadlessJS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) equivalent solution in Flutter to trigger dart code from native side **in background**!

For example, I want to define in the 'Android side' a BroadcastReceiver with BOOT_COMPLETE and then, I reboot the phone, and when its onReceive method get called, to trigger dart code in the 'Flutter side' (maybe through EventChannel) and this will be done totally in the background.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Maybe this is duplicate of your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520563/call-flutter-function-from-android-part-of-the-app

Comment: I guess it is quite similar, and as it mentioned there unfortunately it can't be done?